# Does sudo apt list --upgradeable show kernel updates?

Tags: apt, updates

I was wondering whether

```
sudo apt list --upgradeable
```

shows kernel updates in the list or not?

Comment: Kubuntu 16.04 64bit

Comment: Why would it not? Kernel packages are upgraded in the same way as other packages...

Comment: Note that `apt list` can, and thus should, be run without `sudo`.

Comment: @fkraiem could you develop why? _can ⇏ should_, if so `apt` probably should return a warning when run without `sudo`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it does. After you run `sudo apt-get update`, if there's a kernel update, then `apt list --upgradeable` should show some packages like `linux-headers-4.4.0-something` and `linux-image-4.4.0-something`.

Comment: Thank you , and to actually update them I have to use dist-upgrade instead of just upgrade yes ? Or has that changed ? Does just upgrade update kernels as well now ?

Comment: I always use `dist-upgrade` so I'm not quite sure. But I believe that kernel updates are available because `linux-image-generic` is installed. `dist-upgrade` is used to resolve dependencies so it will probably matter only if the kernel upgrade needs to remove something it's already installed (maybe when 16.04.1 is released, I don't know). For typical bug fixes that cannonical releases, I believe that both `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade` should work.

Comment: Although running apt list --upgradeable does reveal that a kernel update is available by listing [metapackages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages#Kernel_Metapackages) (whose names, like `linux-image-generic`, don't contain a version number), it does not typically show packages with version numbers in the package name, like `linux-image-4.4.0-something`, because those packages are not even installed yet. Upgrading an installed kernel metapackage pulls it in by declaring it as a new dependency.

Answer (score 2):

#### Only the updated kernel [metapackages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages#Kernel_Metapackages) are typically shown in the output of `apt list --upgradeable`.

Nearly all kernel updates are provided as new packages, rather than as new versions of existing packages, so you can keep your old kernels for a while in case the update breaks something and you need to boot the system with an older kernel. These are the packages that have version numbers in their names, like `linux-image-4.15.0-60-generic`.

In order to make it so you receive such packages updates, there are kernel metapackages that server the sole purpose of declaring the packages that actually provide the kernel as dependencies. When new kernel packages are released, the metapackages are themselves updated to depend on it.

Those metapackages show as upgradeable in the output of `apt list --upgradeable`, which is correct because you already have them installed and a new version is available. The new packages are *not* listed here, because you don't have them yet. As [pbojczuk observed](https://askubuntu.com/a/1168223/22949), those packages are not going to be *upgraded*, they're going to be *installed*.

It's possible for those packages to appear in the output of `apt list --upgradeable`, but rare. This could happen if an update were issued to fix a problem that doesn't change the kernel itself. For example, if there were a bug in the installation or removal scripts for a package that provides kernel files, the fix for that bug would likely be provided as an update to that package, *not* as a separate kernel package with a version in the name.

---

#### You can see what will actually be done by running `apt -s upgrade`.

After running `sudo apt update` to retrieve information about what packages are available from where and in what versions, running `apt list --upgradeable` lists the metapackages but not the packages that actually provide the new kernel and associated files:

```
ek@Kip:~$ apt list --upgradeable
Listing... Done
linux-generic/bionic-proposed 4.15.0.60.62 i386 [upgradable from: 4.15.0.59.61]
linux-headers-generic/bionic-proposed 4.15.0.60.62 i386 [upgradable from: 4.15.0.59.61]
linux-image-generic/bionic-proposed 4.15.0.60.62 i386 [upgradable from: 4.15.0.59.61]
linux-libc-dev/bionic-proposed 4.15.0-60.67 i386 [upgradable from: 4.15.0-59.66]
```

If you want to see everything that would be installed by running `sudo apt upgrade` without actually running it, you can tell `apt` to run a simulation, using `apt -s upgrade`:

```
ek@Kip:~$ apt -s upgrade
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-60 linux-headers-4.15.0-60-generic linux-image-4.15.0-60-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-60-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-60-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev
4 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst linux-modules-4.15.0-60-generic (4.15.0-60.67 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-proposed [i386])
Inst linux-image-4.15.0-60-generic (4.15.0-60.67 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-proposed [i386])
Inst linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-60-generic (4.15.0-60.67 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-proposed [i386])
Inst linux-generic [4.15.0.59.61] (4.15.0.60.62 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-proposed [i386]) []
Inst linux-image-generic [4.15.0.59.61] (4.15.0.60.62 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-proposed [i386]) []
Inst linux-headers-4.15.0-60 (4.15.0-60.67 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-proposed [all]) []
Inst linux-headers-4.15.0-60-generic (4.15.0-60.67 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-proposed [i386]) []
Inst linux-headers-generic [4.15.0.59.61] (4.15.0.60.62 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-proposed [i386])
Inst linux-libc-dev [4.15.0-59.66] (4.15.0-60.67 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-proposed [i386])
Conf linux-modules-4.15.0-60-generic (4.15.0-60.67 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-proposed [i386])
Conf linux-image-4.15.0-60-generic (4.15.0-60.67 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-proposed [i386])
Conf linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-60-generic (4.15.0-60.67 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-proposed [i386])
Conf linux-generic (4.15.0.60.62 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-proposed [i386])
Conf linux-image-generic (4.15.0.60.62 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-proposed [i386])
Conf linux-headers-4.15.0-60 (4.15.0-60.67 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-proposed [all])
Conf linux-headers-4.15.0-60-generic (4.15.0-60.67 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-proposed [i386])
Conf linux-headers-generic (4.15.0.60.62 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-proposed [i386])
Conf linux-libc-dev (4.15.0-60.67 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-proposed [i386])
```

This isn't the only way to do it, but when you want to find out what an upgrade will do before performing it, it's the way I suggest. The output is usually very easy to understand, and because it may reveal other unexpected effects of the upgrade you're about to do.

<sub>The output I showed is from a machine on which the `-proposed` repositories are enabled and new kernels are installed from them. (Note that this isn't usually a good idea on production machines, because those kernels are not fully tested on Ubuntu quite yet.) But you'll see similar output with fully stable kernel packages provides in `-security` or `-updates`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Actually I do not see kernel packages via `apt list --upgradable`. Compare:

```
apt list --upgradable | wc -l
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
141
```

Against:

```
apt --recon upgrade | grep ^Inst | wc -l
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
145
```

And the latter value is matching the upgrade result when I check the log `/var/log/apt/history` and calculate values for the `Install:` and `Upgrade:` rows. The kernel packages are placed in `Install:` row there.

Comment: This is correct, but note that it is still possible to know that a new kernel is going to be installed by `sudo apt upgrade` by inspecting the output of `apt list --upgradeable`. The packages that actually provide new kernels (named like `linux-image-4.15.0-60-generic`) are not shown in the output of `apt --list upgradeable` (except under some strange situations), because, as you say, they are going to be newly installed, not upgraded. However, the kernel metapackages (named like `linux-image-generic`) that cause this to happen by depending on then new kernel *are* listed.